# Замена знака "+" в ссылке на изображения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Как при помощи регулярных выражений заменить в строке знак "+" на %2b только там, где он находится в ссылке на изображение. К примеру

> `<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=5+5"/>`

Заменить "+" - но остальные плюсы в строке не трогать - только там, где он находится в img.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=5+5"/> + + п ип + <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chl=5+5+"/>';

str = str.replace(/(src="[^"]+")/g, function (a, b) {
  return b.replace(/\+/g, '%2b');
});

alert(str);
```

[**Проверка.**](http://jsfiddle.net/M8CMF/1/)

Comment: <SCRIPT src="getjs.php?jo+jo"></SCRIPT>

Comment: Оно работает как надо, но плюс еще удаляет src=" " в тэге <img /> :)

Comment: @Smer4ik, исправил.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо тебе )